# Can I utilize two factor authentication from Google, etc to authenticate users to access my site?

Tags: two-factor-authentication

I wish to allow users with Google, Facebook, etc accounts to access my site however can I get them to utilize two factor authentictaion to access the site? Assuming it is posisble, how do I need to do, consider, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OpenID to allow users to authenticate to your site via their Google or Facebook accounts. See:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

once you have OpenID enabled on your site. Users who have Google or Facebook two-factor authentication enabled will still be able to authenticate to your site assuming they succesfully pass 2-factor to Google or Facebook.

Jay